# Flutter - how to align badge icon in toolbar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I use [badges package](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) in my flutter app.  This is my code:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("test"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    Badge(
      position: BadgePosition.topRight(top: 0, right: 2),
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      animationType: BadgeAnimationType.slide,
      badgeContent: Text(
        '7',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), onPressed: () {}),
    ),
  ],
)
```

This is my result:

[image]

But Icons are not aligned vertically.
  I want to vertically align the cart icon. so that it is on the same level as the title and the search icon.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: you want that badge in center vertical of that wallet icon ?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap your Badge with a Center widget:

```
Center(
  child: Badge(
    position: BadgePosition.topRight(top: 0, right: 2),
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    animationType: BadgeAnimationType.slide,
    badgeContent: Text(
      '7',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    child:
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), onPressed: () {}),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Earlier:**

[image]

**Now:**

[image]

Simply wrap your `Badge` in `Align` or `Center`.

```
Align(
  child: Badge(
    position: BadgePosition.topRight(top: 0, right: 2),
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    animationType: BadgeAnimationType.slide,
    badgeContent: Text(
      '7',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), onPressed: () {}),
  ),
)
```